# wso2 ESB 4.9.0 api handler issue

Tags: api, wso2, handler, esb

We had added Handler to WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 api for Basic Authorization but it is not getting saved permanently. When we check from the UI after sometime we are not able to see the handler and The handler is not  working.

`<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{Id}/XXXX">
          <inSequence>
             <sequence key="XXXXSequence"/>
          </inSequence>
     </resource>
     <handlers>
        <handler class="XXXX">
             <property name="securityToken" value="XXXX"/>
        </handler>
      </handlers>
    </api>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3395
And the solution is to use [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/). WSO2 does not recommend using the UI to do development, it is mainly used to monitor and view the instance.